# AWS Elastic Beanstalk and Route 53 Domain linking - "DNS Not found"

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-route53

[image]

I have a EB instance that I want to connect to a domain and I bought the domain from Route 53. The domain should go to the same index page as the original envname.xxxxxx.us-east-2.elas...lk.com url for the instance.

I followed the instructions [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/routing-to-beanstalk-environment.html#routing-to-beanstalk-environment-create-alias-procedure) but still seem to be having some issues with the connection.

When I visit the website, I get "*server DNS address could not be found*" on Chrome.

I added the "url" of my instance to the Record Set Type "A" IPv4 address and selected the EB instance from the list.

Any idea what I may be missing?

Comment: Why A record name is *.lfx....com? In general this will be domain name like abc.com isn't it? and what is the difference between first A entry and second A entry in the screenshot?

Comment: @kosa the first one has a blank "name" and the second one has a * as it's name, I read that the latter redirects any subdomains to the specified instance.

Comment: I would try by removing the sub-domain entry. If I understand correctly, you need to have any other hosted zone for sub-domain(I didn't get chance to try that yet, so not 100% confident).

Comment: @kosa I did! Doesn't seem to help

Comment: Whatever the A record you have there now, it has same name as your hostedzone, is that correct? can update question with new screenshot? What is the error code you are getting?

Comment: @kosa thanks for all the help! I found the solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the solution!

The Nameservers under Domains -> Registered Domains didn't match the ones that were auto populated when I tried to create a new Hosted Zone. I replaced the "NS" servers above with the ones listed under Domains -> Registered Domains -> Name Servers

Answer (score 0):

Check if you can open the Site when in Incognito Mode (press Ctrl+Shift+n). If you can, there's likely a Extension the source of the Problem
Enter this in the Address Bar, chrome://net-internals/#dns, then click the button "Clear Host Cache"
Open a Command Window (Press Ctrl+Esc, then enter cmd), then type this command: ipconfig /flushdns

Comment: Thanks for the reply! This still occurs in incongnito mode.